# awk script for large file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

A file I am working with looks lik

```
Mutation: {"seq-pos":4621.88, "time":0.280423, 1.28819, 1.35223}
[17179](((((112:0.0145017,(142:0.00930338,25:0.00930338):0.00519828):0.00880547,(33:0.00627446,(51:0.00314998,(63:0.000494482,(60:7.$
Mutation: {"seq-pos":34226.9, "time":0.280423, 0.3161, 1.35223}
[34782](((((112:0.0145017,(142:0.00930338,25:0.00930338):0.00519828):0.00880547,(33:0.00627446,(51:0.00314998,(63:0.000494482,(60:7.$
[24088](((((112:0.0145017,(142:0.00930338,25:0.00930338):0.00519828):0.00880547,(33:0.00627446,(51:0.00314998,(63:0.000494482,(60:7.$
Mutation: {"seq-pos":80666, "time":0, 0.0936928, 0.114032}
[16807]((((71:0.00394144,(32:0.000204658,(145:5.25517e-05,27:5.25517e-05):0.000152107):0.00373678):0.150355,(68:0.0393174,((125:0.00$
[7144](((68:0.0393174,((125:0.00135707,70:0.00135707):0.0295768,((((110:0.00771258,95:0.00771258):0.000175535,((85:0.00143738,54:0.0$
segsites: 14
positions: 0.0462188 0.273957 0.275629 0.284955 0.30393 0.342269 0.364361 0.433485 0.730241 0.750358 0.80666 0.80674 0.846499 0.9809$
10001100100100
00000010000000
10001100100100
10000100100000
10000100100100
10010100100000
10001100100100
00000010000000
10000100100100
10000100100100
10000100100100
10000100100100
10000100100100
10001101100100
```

the current script with which I par is

```
!body && /^\/\/$/              {body=1}
body  && sub(/^gthcont: */,"") {print > "second_"FILENAME}
body  && /^[01]+/              {print > "third_"FILENAME}
body  && /^\[[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?\]/ {
    print > "first_"FILENAME
    print substr($0, 2, index($0,"]")-2) > "fourth_"FILENAME
}
```

so the first file contains all lines startin with [], the second all the positions, the thrid the 01 lines adn the fourthall the numbers in brackets. 
I woul need to get a fifth file which stores the mutations
thsi file would look like

```
4621.88 0.280423 1.28819 1.35223
34226.9 0.280423  0.3161  1.35223
80666 0  0.0936928 0.114032
```

which steps would i need to change the script shown abov? that would be great

my idea was

```
/^Mutation/ {gsub(/[^0-9. ]/,""); print >"fifth_"FILENAME}
```

but does not do what i want

if i do..

```
!body && /^\/\/$/              {body=1}
body  && sub(/^gthcont: */,"") {print > "second_"FILENAME}
body  && /^[01]+/              {print > "third_"FILENAME}
body  && /^\[[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?\]/ {
    print > "first_"FILENAME
    print substr($0, 2, index($0,"]")-2) > "fourth_"FILENAME
}
  /^Mutation/ {gsub(/[^0-9. ]/,""); print >"fifth_"FILENAME}
```

it is not working...get not a fith fil

Comment: In what way does your proposed script not do what you want? It looks like it'd do what you want to me.

Comment: dont knwo how to incorpora the rest with that skrip...do i need aa s u b around the last lin?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include complete input data; it looks as if your sample cuts off at 132 columns. Difficult to parse structured data when some of the structure is missing.

Comment: @kagh just add it after the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, or last line. idk what you mean by `do i need aa s u b around the last lin?`.

Comment: coudl smaybe somebody provide a solution whic incorporates the alst line..if i just include it as last line in the file it does not work..see edit..yes th file is also trunctutated but it really does nto matter

Comment: @ morton edited the question

Comment: Is the shown data remotely complete?  Why are there `$` marks at the end of long lines part way through numbers with multiple unmatched open parentheses beforehand?  It looks as though those lines are too long for you to manage to paste easily into the question.  Frankly, I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @kagh it is not possible for the script you show to not create a "fifth_" file from the input you posted therefore either you are not showing us the correct input or you are not showing us the actual script you are running.

Answer (score 0):

If you can depend on the structure, this awk hack will do

```
awk -F"[:,}]" '/^Mutation/{print $3,$5,$6,$7}'
```

I'm not sure how it's going to play with the rest of the script.

If you have to embed into the existing script without changing the field delimiter, this will work

```
$ awk '/^Mutation/ {gsub(/[[:alpha:]]/,"");gsub(/[{\-":,}]/,""); print}' data.txt 
4621.88 0.280423 1.28819 1.35223
34226.9 0.280423 0.3161 1.35223
80666 0 0.0936928 0.114032
```

remove all alpha and punctuation marks, what's left will be your numbers.  Note that it removes `-` which might be the sign of a number as well, so this is not a robust script. (You can't use `[[:punct:]]` which will remove the decimal point as well).  I'm not sure if there is a POSIX char class for decimal numbers.

Comment: please use the edit..is a solution with the code i used  possible?